# Sort a Javascript object based on value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have this json object:

```
obj = {
    "name":
    {
        "display": "Name",
        "id": "name",
        "position": 3           
    },
    "type":
    {
        "id": "type",
        "position": 0
    },
    "id":
    {
        "display": "ID",
        "id": "id",
        "position": 1
    }
    "key":
    {
        "display": "Key",
        "id": "key",
        "position": 2
    },

}
```

Is it possible to sort it based on their position numbers, without converting it to an array? 
I tried to convert it but it changes the format (it deletes the name,type,id,key) and I don't want this.. It should stay as it is (the format) but just in order based on their position.

what i did:

```
var array = $.map(obj, function(value, index) {
            return [value];
        });

        array.sort(function(a,b){
            return a.position - b.position;
        });
        obj= JSON.stringify(array);
        obj= JSON.parse(obj);
```

Comment: objects have no order, you must use an array

Comment: Have you tried to search for an answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/482868

Comment: @Vic isn't possible to swap the place of the keys??

Comment: @johnmmm no, it's not possible

Comment: unfortunately it is not possible to achieve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In agreement with the first comments of your question, you should replace your object with an array and remove the redundancies.
The position will be determined by that of the element in the array and the keys of your elements will no longer be duplicated with your id properties

EDIT:
With this code you can sort the object but **you can't use id as key** because otherwise it will be sorted again alphabetically instead of position.

```js
    let obj = {
    "name":
    {
        "display": "Name",
        "id": "name",
        "position": 3           
    },
    "type":
    {
        "id": "type",
        "position": 0
    },
    "id":
    {
        "display": "ID",
        "id": "id",
        "position": 1
    },
    "key":
    {
        "display": "Key",
        "id": "key",
        "position": 2
    },
    }
    
    let arr = [];
    for(let i in obj) {
     if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      arr[obj[i].position] = obj[i]
       }
    }
    
    
    let sortedObj = {};
    for(let i in arr) {
     sortedObj[i] = arr[i]
    }
    
    console.log(sortedObj)
```

Comment: I need it to be like this because this is a small part of the code and if i change the json then the rest of the code won't work.. cant i just swap the places of the keys based on the position number??

Comment: You should convert your json to array, sort it as you did it and create a new json object while traveling through that array.

Comment: any clues on how to reconvert it to json and have the same structure?

Comment: Answer edited (code snippet added)

Comment: so in other words there is not a way to sort it without losing the id?

Comment: Yes, there is no way